# Is 'integer + ""' a good way to convert a integer to string in Java?

Tags: java

I always use `String.valueOf(integer)` to convert an integer to a string, but I saw someone to do it by `integer + ""`. For example,

```
int i = 0;
String i0 = i + "";
```

So, is that a good way to convert integer to string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use whatever method is more readable. `String.valueOf(i)` or `Integer.toString(i)` make your intent much clearer than `i + ""`.

Comment: Is `String.valueOf` more efficient than `i + ""`?

Comment: @Sayakiss There shouldn't be a difference performance wise (in any decent compiler). You should only worry about readability.

Answer (score 13):

Though it works, `i + ""` is kind of hack to convert `int` to String. The + operator on string never designed to use that way.  Always use `String.valueOf()`

Comment: Nice answer. Also, I think String.valueOf() is cleaner.

Comment: If the `+` operator was  not designed to be used that way, you would not be able to do things like `System.out.println("i=" + i)`.   That would be like programming in Modula 2 again.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Agreed, but again you are free to do that and it works absolutely. But I'm just saying that it's kind of misusing it for sake. Just suggested a cleaner way :)

Comment: Then you cannot say "never designed to be used that way", as it is very clear from the JLS that it is deliberate.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, what is the purpose of `+` operator for Strings??

Answer (score 3):

It's not only the optimization. I don't like

```
"" + i
```

because it does not express what I really want to do.

I don't want to append an integer to an (empty) string. I want to convert an integer to string:

```
Integer.toString(i)
```

Or, not my prefered, but still better than concatenation, get a string representation of an object (integer

```
String.valueOf(i)
```

N.B: *For code that is called very often, like in loops, optimization sure is also a point for not using concatenation.*

Answer (score 3):

The thing there is that if you have an `Integer i` (non-primitive) and use `i + ""`, you may end up with a non-null string of `"null"` value if `i` is null, while `String.valueOf(...)` will throw `NullPointerException` in this case.

In all other cases it's the same (also very similar as for the internal process that will be invoked to return the result). Given what's above, it all depends on the context that you use it for, e.x. if you plan to convert the string back to `int`/`Integer` the `+` case, may be more problematic.